# API provides too many photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

SELECT object_id, src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner=)

I use this query to get photos of some user, which is friend of other user, which provided friend_photos permissions for my app. And I get a lot of photos. Now, when I open this profile in Facebook (and I'm not a friend of this user), I don't see most of these photos (probably they are only for friends).

Question is: how do I filter such non-public photos with the API? I don't need anything that is not visible to general public...

There is album visibility field, but it's available only to album owner.

Comment: The Facebook API does not have a way to filter on non-public items. The best you could do would be to make 2 queries. One with the friend's access token and one with a generic app access token and then compare the two results. You're definitely in the "creepy" range and possibly violating the TOS with this one, so tread carefully.

Comment: The catch is that with generic app access token I don't get any photos at all. So I've got nothing to compare.

Comment: You could try this with your user accounts access token, but I'm sure that's a violation of the TOS.

Comment: With non-friend access token I get nothing as well...

Comment: Then you know how many of that user's photos are visible to everyone: Zero.

Comment: It is so for ANY profile. The only way to get pictures with with friends_photos permission. At least my tests show so.